# Masonry random sized images

Tags: jquery, image, random, jquery-masonry

I'm using jQuery Masonry to make a photography page with tiles containing different photos.

All of the images going onto the website are the same dimensions/aspect ratio so the only thing making it 'masonry' is lining portrait and landscape photos up together. Currently they line up in a table type grid mostly.
Is there a way to use jQuery masonry to make the images random sizes or apply different css classes which alters their width, so the pictures are lined up in a grid iQn different sizes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you trying , you want implement masonry view or you are facing any issue ?

Comment: Trying to implement random sizes of the photos. Currently all the photos are all 1200x800 and although masonry resizes them, they all resize to the same size/aspect ratio. Is it possible to get masonry to automatically make all the photos different sizes (like the 'After' side here: http://cct460-s12.wikispaces.com/file/view/Screen%20shot%202012-08-02%20at%204.25.43%20PM.png/357535940/Screen%20shot%202012-08-02%20at%204.25.43%20PM.png)?

Comment: Yes. Masonry automatically re-size on page load. you need to call masonry js on your container div